# How to avoid this ValueError during concatenation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to concatenate a list of pandas Dataframes with only one column each, but I keep getting this error:

*ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8980, 2), indices imply (200, 2)*

I made sure that all the shapes are identical (200 rows × 1 columns) and I removed all the NA values. The concatenation works along the rows (axis=0) but doesn't work along the columns (axis=1).

I previously manipulated the Dataframes with some Transpositions `df.T` and with other operations like `dropna(axis=0, how='all')`. I don't think that this could be the cause for the error because  I tried it on a toy dataset and it worked fine. Here's some code for context:

```
test_full[:3] #this is what my list of pandas Dataframes looks like (the first 3 items)

 [Unnamed: 1 
 1               3520
 2               2014
 3              10253 
 4               5929
 1               3243
 ..               ...
 
 [200 rows x 1 columns],
 Unnamed: 2 
 1                   2476
 2                   1455
 3                   7245
 4                   4304
 1                   2275
 ..                   ...
 
 [200 rows x 1 columns],
 Unnamed: 3
 1                  1044
 2                   559
 3                  3008
 4                  1625
 1                   968
 ..                  ...
 
 [200 rows x 1 columns]]
```

For the Concatenation I tried:

`pd.concat(test_full, axis=1)`

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-f067bc5875c9> in <module>
----> 1 pd.concat(test_full, axis=1)

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8980, 104), indices imply (200, 104)
```

As an output I was hoping for:

```
           Unnamed: 1    Unnamed:2    Unnamed:3
 1               3520         1232         6349
 2               2014         4353         2974
 3              10253         1234         1223
 4               5929         7456         9854
 1               3243         7654        11034
 ..               ...         ...         ...
```

I also don't really know what the `Shape (8980, 104)` and the `indices imply (200,104)`are referring to.

I would really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: It could be the one dataframe inside the list has different dimensions. Otherwise, the code should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, this error tends to happen if either index has duplicate values as it doesn't know how to handle it. From your example, it seems like you have multiple 1s. If this isn't necessary, you could call `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` for each dataframe before concatenating.

This issue doesn't occur when you concatenate along the index as it just "puts them on top of each other", regardless of what the index is.

What the error message is telling you is that the resulting shape is `(8980, 104)` but that the expected shape should be `(200, 104)` based on the index.